# how to make a patteren like 12345-1234567-8 using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to midify this code mean after 5 character hyphen "-" is auto inserted and then after 7 character hyphen "-" is inserted. but in this code only after 5 character hyphen is inserted.

```
<html>
<head>
      <script>    
        $('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
          var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
          if (foo.length > 0) {
            foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,5}', 'g')).join("-");
          }
          $(this).val(foo);
        });
      </script>
</heead>
<body>
      <input type="text" class="creditCardText" />
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/126/

Comment: something like this: `'12345123456712345678'.replace(/^(.{5})(.{7})(.)/g, '$1-$2-$3')` ?

Comment: @pomeh You mean, something like my answer? :)

Comment: @Madbreaks Actually, "your answer is more like his comment.." :P

Comment: @Vega Ha, I hadn't noticed that! His comment wasn't there when I started my answer though.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can match the whole string of numbers, and split them into chunks like this:

```js
var num = "1234512345671";
alert("Parsed: " + num.replace(/(\d{5})(\d{7})(\d)/, "$1-$2-$3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**An Alternate approach without RegEx**

**Edit:** Updated to add hypens as you type.

You could use `.slice` the string and then insert at desired position. See below code and demo.

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 5 && foo.length < 13) {
    foo = foo.slice(0, 5) + '-' + foo.slice(5);
  } else if (foo.length >= 13) {
    foo = foo.slice(0, 5) + '-' + foo.slice(5);
    foo = foo.slice(0, 13) + '-' + foo.slice(13);
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" />
```

Comment: @MuhammadHassan See my updates.. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Glad it worked for you. Make sure you accept the best suited answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot #Vega. its working perfect. but is it possible when enter first 5 character then hyphen "-" is inserted and then after 7 character hyphen "-" is inserted? In you code when complete character 13 character is entered then hyphen is inserted. thanx –

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length == 13) {
     foo = foo.slice(0, 5) + '-' + foo.slice(5);
     foo = foo.slice(0, 13) + '-' + foo.slice(13);
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" />
```

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length == 13) {
     foo = foo.slice(0, 5) + '-' + foo.slice(5);
     foo = foo.slice(0, 13) + '-' + foo.slice(13);
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" />
```